# What does "curl up" mean

Tags: meaning

I can't understand a phrase "I see a curl up around your smile". Please someone explain me what it means? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lyrics from the song *Sugar* on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elsie_(album) . In the song, it seems to indicate a betrayal of insincerity of love in a romantic relationship.

Comment: You are welcome. To be clear, this is only a line in a song. I would not understand the idea of a *curl up around a smile* on its own, and it will not make sense in ordinary communication.

Comment: @JimReynolds, you mean 'betrayal of insincerity ' or betrayal 'or' insincerity of love..? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: It is a betrayal (unintentional revelation) of insincerity. My interpretation of the song is essentially: You won't stay with me / you aren't committed to me / I'm temporary for you  ... but you claim this is not the case. You claim to love me (you smile), but there is something a little different about that smile, a certain shape in a certain part of it, that shows it is not honest. So the curl betrays (reveals) the lie. The lie is that you're here for me, you'll stay with me, you love me.

Comment: haha=) this is the best explanation ever=)

Comment: Do you really mean it, user3127896? Your =)'s seem to have little curls up around them. O.O

Comment: The OP has an answer. This is apparently a request for an interpretation of a song lyric. I'm flagging to close as off-topic because answers would be expected to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting song lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

Denotation: To roll something.  [Here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/curl+up)

Connotation: Being extremely embarrassed. [Here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=curl%20up)

Comment: A nouning of an informal multi-word verb! But it looks like the correct explanation.